# I'm at loss with a recursive method on leetcode 72

Tags: c++, string, recursion

Though it will be TLE,I think it's useful for me to understand the valid solution which use **Dynamic Programming**,here is the Description and the code:

*Given two words word1 and word2, find the minimum number of steps required to convert word1 to word2. (each operation is counted as 1 step.)
You have the following 3 operations permitted on a word:
a) Insert a character
b) Delete a character
c) Replace a character*

```
int minDistance(string word1, string word2) {
        if(word1 == word2) return 0;

        int m = word1.size();
        int n = word2.size();

        if(word1 == "")
        {
            return n;
        }

        if(word2 == "")
        {
            return m;
        }

        if(word1[0] == word2[0])
        {
            return minDistance(word1.substr(1), word2.substr(1));
        }
        else
        {
            return min(1 + minDistance(word1, word2.substr(1)), min(1 + minDistance(word1.substr(1), word2), 1 + minDistance(word1.substr(1), word2.substr(1))));
        }

    }
```

One question is that I can't understand the ELSE Structure's meaning for sure--In my opinion,it has three different situations,so I guess it respectively achieves **insert** **delete** and **replace**(Maybe the order is incorrect)
Another is how to understand when one string is empty,the result will be the other string's length?

Comment: OMG, Levenstein distance as a programming contest task.

Answer (score 0):

```
return 
min
(
1 + minDistance(word1, word2.substr(1)), <-insert from word2
1 + minDistance(word1.substr(1), word2), <-delete from word1
1 + minDistance(word1.substr(1), word2.substr(1)) <-replace
)
```

Firstly,
the "insert" case implies that we take a first character from word2 and insert it into word1 (and increment the "edit distance" cost), which leaves us with word1 and word2.substr(1)

the "delete" case implies that we throw away a first character of word1 (and increment the "edit distance" cost), which leaves us with word1.substr(1) and word2

the "replace" case implies that the first chars of both words are different so we increment "edit distance" cost and throw away the first chars which leaves us with word1.substr(1) and word2.substr(1)

the "same" case implies that the first chars of both words are the same so we don't need to increment "edit distance" cost and hence we just throw away the first chars which leaves us with word1.substr(1) and word2.substr(1)

Hence we have 3 different possibilities to check, that's why we recursively call the function for all 3 cases and compare their final costs by picking up the minimal one.

Secondly,
the base case "return n" implies that in order to convert empty string into word2 we definitely need to insert n chars from word2 into word1 which adds "n" to the "edit distance" cost
Similarly, the base case "return m" implies that in order to convert word1 into empty string we definitely need to delete m chars from word1 which adds "m" to the "edit distance" cost

Your algorithm is a special case of a more general "edit distance" algorithm which can be applied to the wide range of problems by modifying the cost of insert/delete/replace/same. For your specific case, the goal is to find the minimum number of steps needed to convert word1 into word2 so the cost=1 for "insert/delete/replace" and cost=0 for "same" would be the solution.

Regarding dynamic programming version of the algorithm, it is straightforward to derive it, once you have defined the recursion and necessary base cases.

Comment: A direct and brilliant answer,thanks you a lot! But I still have a little question about the INSERT case,why the word1's length remain rather than plus one is that we should throw away a char anyway,but now we add one,so they are offset,can I understand it like this?

Comment: @heiheihei hahaha, think of it as a cost to convert one string into another, not the form of strings itself. Also note that word1 and word2 are NOT original strings, rather they are the arguments of recursive call. If our next step is "insert" (because it has a minimal cost), we now are interested in the cost of converting word1 into word2 WITHOUT its first char. Similarly if our next step is "delete", we will now be interested in the cost of converting word1 WITHOUT its first char into word2

Comment: The chars added into ORIGINAL word1 from ORIGINAL word2 as well as chars removed from ORIGINAL word1 are kept separate from the cost calculation, they do not participate in the further process. We just know that they exist. In order to restore the sequence of operations and visualize which char was inserted/removed at which step, the algorithm should be enhanced to support backtracking, i.e. all the path from the final state to the first state.

Comment: The mutated word1 with inserted/deleted chars and word2 with deleted chars are not involved in the cost calculation. When calculating the cost, we (naturally) consider only original word1 and word2, not modified ones